# MySQL: Include days with zero orders in a list of orders per day

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

```
Date|OrderID
2012-03-09|123
2012-03-09|122
2012-03-07|121
```

And I am doing a query like this

```
SELECT Date, COUNT(OrderID) FROM Table GROUP BY Date
```

I want to include days with zero orders in this list.

Is there an elegant solution for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your `Table` is the orders table, then no. A query will not produce rows/data that does not already exist in the database. If there are no order records for a particular day, you won't get that date in the output.

You could generate a temp table that contains every date within a particular range and join against that - then you'd actually have all of the necessary dates and would get a 0-orders count for the quiet days.

Comment: Very nice solution but how can I do that if I use Unix format dates? I cant figure it out? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: mysql can convert between native- and unix-style with `from_unixtime()` and `unix_timestamp()`